# Using html in Magnific pop up title attribute

Tags: html, css, magnific-popup

I need to wrap certain bits of my title attribute in html tags in order to style them for when I click an element and it pops up on Magnific Popup. I am trying something like bellow at the moment:

```
 <a href="path/to/img" title='<span class="date">2016 -</span> Title text goes here'> Content goes here </a>
```

However, if I add html tags in the title attribute as I have above it will then show them with the html tags and title text when hovering the element with the title attribute like bellow:

```
<span class="date">2016 -</span> Title text goes here
```

How could I implement this so that I can still style the date and have it rendering without the html tags on hover like:

```
2016 - Title text goes here
```

Comment: have you tried changing the quotes? making title=".. and ... class='date'?

Comment: No, it will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using javascript for that an in your initialization code do something like that:

```
titleSrc: function() {
    return "<span class='date'>2016 -</span> Title text goes here";
}
```

As said in [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#image-type)

Comment: I gave the example above to simplify things but I am actually using this in a WordPress website and this will be inside a loop which will echo the title with the date and other text from the database. So, this option wont be ideal as I need this to be dynamic.